# Modeling infinity for the largest double value

Tags: c++, double, infinity

The question is about modeling infinity in C++ for the `double` data type.  I need it in a header file, so we cannot use functions like `numeric_limits`.

Is there a defined constant that represents the largest value?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

floating point numbers(such as doubles) can actually hold positive and negative infinity. The constant INFINITY should be in your math.h header.

Went standard diving and found the text:

> 4 The macro INFINITY expands to a constant expression of type float
> representing positive or unsigned infinity, if available; else to a
> positive constant of type float that overflows at translation time.

In Section `7.12 Mathematics <math.h>`

---

Then of course you have the helper function `isinf` to test for infinity(which is also in math.h).

> 7.12.3.3 The isinf macro
>
> int isinf(real-floating x);
>
> Description: The isinf macro determines whether its argument value is an infinity (positive
> or negative). First, an argument represented in a format wider than
> its semantic type is converted to its semantic type. Then
> determination is based on the type of the argument.
>
> Returns: The
> isinf macro returns a nonzero value if and only if its argument has an
> infinite value.

Comment: @JamWaffles The C standards are actually surprisingly readable. It's the C++ standards which seem to be written by overzealous language lawyers.

Comment: Since the question is technically asking what for "C++" the #include <cmath> header should be used instead of #include <math.h>.

Answer (score 21):

`numeric_limits` functions are all constexpr so they work just fine as compile time constants (assuming you're using the current version of C++). So `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()` ought to work in any context.

Even if you're using an older version, this will still work anywhere that you don't require a compile time constant. It's not clear from your question if your use really needs a compile time constant or not; just being in a header doesn't necessarily require it.

If you are using an older version, and you really do need a compile time constant, the macro `INFINITY` in cmath should work for you. It's actually the `float` value for infinity, but it can be converted to a `double`.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure why you can't use std::numeric_limits in a header file. But there is also this carried over from ANSI C:

```
#include <cfloat>

DBL_MAX
```

Answer (score 2):

DBL_MAX can be used. This is found in float.h as follows

```
    #define DBL_MAX         1.7976931348623158e+308 /* max value */
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought the answer was "[42.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28number%29)" ;)

This article might be of interest:

http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Or this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cfloat/

MAXimum Maximum finite representable floating-point number:

```
FLT_MAX  1E+37
DBL_MAX  1E+37
LDBL_MAX 1E+37
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in your C++ environment you have `float.h`, see http://www.gamedev.net/topic/392211-max-value-for-double-/ (DBL_MAX)

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision):

```
0x 7ff0 0000 0000 0000   = Infinity
0x fff0 0000 0000 0000   = −Infinity
```

Comment: Of course, the OP might be on a platform that isn't using IEEE floating point numbers.

Comment: I know of no current platforms. But my old 8-bit Atari system did not (and yes, it had floating point). But it's bad form regardless. There's no saying that IEEE floating point will be how things are done in ten years. This invites the creation of another 'millenium bug'.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cmath>
...
double d = INFINITY;
```

You can find `INFINITY` defined in `<cmath>` ([`math.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/math.h.html)):

> A constant expression of type **`float`** representing positive or unsigned infinity, if available; else a positive constant of type **`float`** that overflows at translation time.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't this work?

```
const double infinity =  1.0/0.0;
```